# what different between InternalResourceViewResolver vs UrlBasedViewResolver

Tags: java, spring

I just started using Spring. I came across a lot tutorials.
I saw more examples using `InternalResourceViewResolver` than `UrlBasedViewResolver`. I looked at the Spring documentation, but I can't figure out the benefit of using one or the other. Can someone provide some explanation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`InternalResourceViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) is a convenient subclass of [`UrlBasedViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html).

The JavaDoc describes some added properties in `InternalResourceViewResolver` that might be useful in some situations:

> Convenient subclass of UrlBasedViewResolver that supports [InternalResourceView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceView.html) (i.e. Servlets and JSPs) and subclasses such as JstlView.

`AlwaysInclude`: Controls whether either a forward or include is done.

`ExposeContextBeansAsAttributes`: Allows all beans in context to be available as request attributes, which means they can be referenced from the EL in JSP.

`ExposedContextBeanNames`: If non-null, specifies the list of beans that will be exposed, as opposed to all of them.

Source from spring forum : [Spring Q&A forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/64551-internalresourceviewresolver-and-urlbasedviewresolver)

Answer (score 8):

Spring supports a wide range of view technologies. ViewResolvers are here to plug any of the known supported view technologies into your application.

[UrlBasedViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html) is a simple view resolver which simply resolves views of different technologies, by matching `URL` patterns to corresponding file names.

`UrlBasedViewResolver` is here to support all the view technologies of type "[AbstractUrlBasedView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.7/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractUrlBasedView.html)".

`AbstractJasperReportsView`, `AbstractPdfStamperView`, `AbstractTemplateView`, `InternalResourceView`, `RedirectView`, `TilesView`, `XsltView` are the known subclasses of `AbstractUrlBasedView`.

So when you are using `UrlBasedViewResolver` you can use any one of the subclasses of `AbstractUrlBasedView` as the type of your view technology (by setting the corresponding viewClass only).

[InternalResourceViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) is a subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

But when you are using `InternalResourceViewResolver`, (which is a convenient subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver`), you can only use the technology of type `InternalResourceView` as your view technology.

I think this answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

`InternalResourceViewResolver` is infact subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver` .

`UrlBasedViewResolver` - View name is directly resolved to an URL. No explicit mapping is provided. View name would be the URL itself or you can add a `prefix` or `suffix` as per your design. You can also prefix as "redirect:" and "forward:" to redirect and forward your request.

`InternalResourceViewResolver` - Subclass of UrlBasedViewResolver that supports InternalResourceView. An `InternalResourceView` wraps JSP or some other resource of the same web app. You can access models in the JSP using EL.

**NOTE** : Some URLBasedViewResolvers (Tiles, Velocity,Freemarker) check if resource exist and return null. So they can be anywhere in the view resolver chain. Others must be last (JSTL/JSP, XSLT, JSON)

So `InternalResourceViewResolver` needs to be last in the chain of view resolvers since it resolves view name whether the actual resource is present or not.

Some other URLBasedViewReolver s are

1. InternalResourceViewResolver
2. VelocityViewReolver
3. FreeMarkerViewReolver
4. ThymeleafViewResolver
5. XsltViewReolver