# What is the exact difference between InternalResourceViewResolver and UrlBasedViewResolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I am not able to understand what was the exact difference, can anyone explain with respect to the flow of mvc with an example which covers the properties like AlwaysInclude, ExposeContextBeansAsAttributes, ExposedContextBeanNames as mentioned in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453032/what-different-between-internalresourceviewresolver-vs-urlbasedviewresolver).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what different between InternalResourceViewResolver vs UrlBasedViewResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453032/what-different-between-internalresourceviewresolver-vs-urlbasedviewresolver)